# How can I create an histogram in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics, genetics

I have a distribution here for each codon: 'AAA', 'AAC' etc, in terms of letters representing amino acids
The distribution is arranged in a dictionary. How can I create an histogram that includes the distribution for each of the 64 codons?

[image: here's what I had in mind for each codon]

```
[['AAA', {'R': 3, 'I': 3, 'S': 5, 'Y': 4, 'P': 4, 'L': 6, 'K': 5, 'D': 9, 'A': 9, 'T': 3, 'G': 3, 'N': 5, 'M': 3, 'W': 7, 'H': 5, 'V': 6, 'Q': 2, 'E': 4, 'F': 6, 'C': 5}], ['AAC', {'R': 7, 'I': 4, 'S': 5, 'Y': 4, 'P': 6, 'L': 4, 'K': 6, 'D': 5, 'A': 6, 'T': 3, 'G': 5, 'N': 5, 'M': 4, 'W': 2, 'H': 3, 'V': 6, 'Q': 7, 'E': 5, 'F': 5, 'C': 5}], ['AAG', {'R': 5, 'I': 6, 'S': 6, 'Y': 3, 'P': 8, 'L': 4, 'K': 6, 'D': 5, 'A': 6, 'T': 4, 'G': 2, 'N': 4, 'M': 2, 'W': 2, 'H': 5, 'V': 7, 'Q': 8, 'E': 5, 'F': 2, 'C': 7}], ['AAU', {'R': 4, 'I': 7, 'S': 3, 'Y': 6, 'P': 7, 'L': 1, 'K': 6, 'D': 3, 'A': 4, 'T': 6, 'G': 6, 'N': 5, 'M': 4, 'W': 5, 'H': 5, 'V': 2, 'Q': 3, 'E': 7, 'F': 6, 'C': 7}], ['ACA', {'R': 7, 'I': 3, 'S': 3, 'Y': 4, 'P': 5, 'L': 5, 'K': 9, 'D': 6, 'A': 3, 'T': 3, 'G': 5, 'N': 6, 'M': 4, 'W': 2, 'H': 9, 'V': 6, 'Q': 2, 'E': 5, 'F': 5, 'C': 5}], ['ACC', {'R': 5, 'I': 3, 'S': 3, 'Y': 5, 'P': 8, 'L': 2, 'K': 8, 'D': 6, 'A': 4, 'T': 3, 'G': 2, 'N': 5, 'M': 8, 'W': 1, 'H': 6, 'V': 4, 'Q': 5, 'E': 5, 'F': 4, 'C': 10}], ['ACG', {'R': 4, 'I': 7, 'S': 6, 'Y': 5, 'P': 3, 'L': 3, 'K': 4, 'D': 7, 'A': 6, 'T': 4, 'G': 6, 'N': 5, 'M': 7, 'W': 4, 'H': 2, 'V': 7, 'Q': 3, 'E': 2, 'F': 5, 'C': 7}], ['ACU', {'R': 12, 'I': 4, 'S': 6, 'Y': 4, 'P': 6, 'L': 5, 'K': 3, 'D': 5, 'A': 4, 'T': 3, 'G': 2, 'N': 5, 'M': 4, 'W': 6, 'H': 6, 'V': 8, 'Q': 1, 'E': 6, 'F': 5, 'C': 2}], ['AGA', {'R': 4, 'I': 4, 'S': 3, 'Y': 3, 'P': 1, 'L': 7, 'K': 1, 'D': 6, 'A': 5, 'T': 6, 'G': 5, 'N': 7, 'M': 7, 'W': 7, 'H': 2, 'V': 5, 'Q': 7, 'E': 5, 'F': 6, 'C': 6}], ['AGC', {'R': 9, 'I': 2, 'S': 3, 'Y': 6, 'P': 1, 'L': 6, 'K': 3, 'D': 2, 'A': 5, 'T': 5, 'G': 3, 'N': 5, 'M': 10, 'W': 7, 'H': 4, 'V': 8, 'Q': 6, 'E': 3, 'F': 7, 'C': 2}], ['AGG', {'R': 5, 'I': 5, 'S': 7, 'Y': 6, 'P': 5, 'L': 4, 'K': 4, 'D': 5, 'A': 3, 'T': 1, 'G': 4, 'N': 7, 'M': 3, 'W': 4, 'H': 4, 'V': 3, 'Q': 4, 'E': 5, 'F': 7, 'C': 11}], ['AGU', {'R': 5, 'I': 10, 'S': 4, 'Y': 5, 'P': 6, 'L': 5, 'K': 6, 'D': 4, 'A': 4, 'T': 4, 'G': 7, 'N': 5, 'M': 3, 'W': 1, 'H': 3, 'V': 3, 'Q': 6, 'E': 7, 'F': 3, 'C': 6}], ['AUA', {'R': 5, 'I': 5, 'S': 4, 'Y': 4, 'P': 5, 'L': 5, 'K': 1, 'D': 4, 'A': 7, 'T': 3, 'G': 8, 'N': 6, 'M': 3, 'W': 6, 'H': 6, 'V': 6, 'Q': 4, 'E': 6, 'F': 7, 'C': 2}], ['AUC', {'R': 4, 'I': 2, 'S': 5, 'Y': 8, 'P': 9, 'L': 6, 'K': 4, 'D': 5, 'A': 4, 'T': 3, 'G': 4, 'N': 8, 'M': 2, 'W': 4, 'H': 6, 'V': 4, 'Q': 7, 'E': 1, 'F': 1, 'C': 10}], ['AUG', {'R': 3, 'I': 7, 'S': 6, 'Y': 6, 'P': 1, 'L': 5, 'K': 6, 'D': 1, 'A': 3, 'T': 4, 'G': 10, 'N': 3, 'M': 4, 'W': 7, 'H': 5, 'V': 6, 'Q': 7, 'E': 7, 'F': 2, 'C': 4}], ['AUU', {'R': 4, 'I': 3, 'S': 2, 'Y': 5, 'P': 5, 'L': 5, 'K': 7, 'D': 4, 'A': 10, 'T': 2, 'G': 3, 'N': 7, 'M': 3, 'W': 7, 'H': 7, 'V': 5, 'Q': 4, 'E': 4, 'F': 6, 'C': 4}], ['CAA', {'R': 6, 'I': 3, 'S': 2, 'Y': 4, 'P': 5, 'L': 10, 'K': 2, 'D': 7, 'A': 6, 'T': 7, 'G': 3, 'N': 4, 'M': 5, 'W': 5, 'H': 5, 'V': 3, 'Q': 8, 'E': 3, 'F': 5, 'C': 4}], ['CAC', {'R': 9, 'I': 4, 'S': 6, 'Y': 5, 'P': 3, 'L': 1, 'K': 1, 'D': 0, 'A': 12, 'T': 7, 'G': 4, 'N': 7, 'M': 2, 'W': 4, 'H': 4, 'V': 9, 'Q': 4, 'E': 8, 'F': 3, 'C': 4}], ['CAG', {'R': 3, 'I': 1, 'S': 6, 'Y': 3, 'P': 7, 'L': 7, 'K': 5, 'D': 5, 'A': 4, 'T': 2, 'G': 3, 'N': 3, 'M': 4, 'W': 6, 'H': 8, 'V': 6, 'Q': 9, 'E': 7, 'F': 5, 'C': 3}], ['CAU', {'R': 5, 'I': 6, 'S': 2, 'Y': 3, 'P': 7, 'L': 7, 'K': 6, 'D': 6, 'A': 1, 'T': 4, 'G': 11, 'N': 7, 'M': 4, 'W': 5, 'H': 4, 'V': 5, 'Q': 2, 'E': 8, 'F': 2, 'C': 2}], ['CCA', {'R': 5, 'I': 7, 'S': 1, 'Y': 2, 'P': 4, 'L': 4, 'K': 5, 'D': 7, 'A': 5, 'T': 7, 'G': 1, 'N': 4, 'M': 9, 'W': 8, 'H': 5, 'V': 6, 'Q': 3, 'E': 3, 'F': 6, 'C': 5}], ['CCC', {'R': 4, 'I': 3, 'S': 8, 'Y': 5, 'P': 4, 'L': 3, 'K': 4, 'D': 6, 'A': 5, 'T': 4, 'G': 4, 'N': 8, 'M': 1, 'W': 7, 'H': 4, 'V': 7, 'Q': 7, 'E': 5, 'F': 3, 'C': 5}], ['CCG', {'R': 3, 'I': 4, 'S': 7, 'Y': 2, 'P': 4, 'L': 3, 'K': 4, 'D': 3, 'A': 6, 'T': 5, 'G': 5, 'N': 3, 'M': 4, 'W': 5, 'H': 8, 'V': 3, 'Q': 5, 'E': 8, 'F': 7, 'C': 8}], ['CCU', {'R': 8, 'I': 3, 'S': 2, 'Y': 5, 'P': 4, 'L': 4, 'K': 2, 'D': 6, 'A': 5, 'T': 6, 'G': 8, 'N': 6, 'M': 4, 'W': 3, 'H': 5, 'V': 4, 'Q': 4, 'E': 7, 'F': 5, 'C': 6}], ['CGA', {'R': 5, 'I': 2, 'S': 6, 'Y': 6, 'P': 6, 'L': 3, 'K': 1, 'D': 5, 'A': 5, 'T': 7, 'G': 5, 'N': 7, 'M': 8, 'W': 4, 'H': 3, 'V': 4, 'Q': 6, 'E': 7, 'F': 5, 'C': 2}], ['CGC', {'R': 4, 'I': 3, 'S': 5, 'Y': 4, 'P': 6, 'L': 3, 'K': 5, 'D': 5, 'A': 6, 'T': 6, 'G': 7, 'N': 1, 'M': 3, 'W': 5, 'H': 3, 'V': 7, 'Q': 8, 'E': 7, 'F': 3, 'C': 6}], ['CGG', {'R': 2, 'I': 3, 'S': 3, 'Y': 6, 'P': 6, 'L': 5, 'K': 6, 'D': 2, 'A': 4, 'T': 4, 'G': 10, 'N': 2, 'M': 3, 'W': 6, 'H': 3, 'V': 3, 'Q': 4, 'E': 6, 'F': 13, 'C': 6}], ['CGU', {'R': 3, 'I': 5, 'S': 1, 'Y': 3, 'P': 9, 'L': 3, 'K': 6, 'D': 4, 'A': 5, 'T': 4, 'G': 4, 'N': 8, 'M': 7, 'W': 5, 'H': 3, 'V': 7, 'Q': 7, 'E': 4, 'F': 5, 'C': 4}], ['CUA', {'R': 7, 'I': 4, 'S': 2, 'Y': 5, 'P': 8, 'L': 6, 'K': 4, 'D': 1, 'A': 5, 'T': 4, 'G': 3, 'N': 3, 'M': 8, 'W': 6, 'H': 5, 'V': 5, 'Q': 5, 'E': 9, 'F': 3, 'C': 4}], ['CUC', {'R': 5, 'I': 3, 'S': 6, 'Y': 6, 'P': 2, 'L': 13, 'K': 2, 'D': 4, 'A': 3, 'T': 3, 'G': 5, 'N': 9, 'M': 2, 'W': 3, 'H': 4, 'V': 7, 'Q': 5, 'E': 2, 'F': 6, 'C': 7}], ['CUG', {'R': 5, 'I': 4, 'S': 5, 'Y': 6, 'P': 5, 'L': 2, 'K': 2, 'D': 5, 'A': 2, 'T': 3, 'G': 3, 'N': 6, 'M': 5, 'W': 9, 'H': 2, 'V': 6, 'Q': 5, 'E': 2, 'F': 7, 'C': 13}], ['CUU', {'R': 8, 'I': 4, 'S': 2, 'Y': 3, 'P': 5, 'L': 6, 'K': 8, 'D': 3, 'A': 5, 'T': 2, 'G': 8, 'N': 2, 'M': 4, 'W': 3, 'H': 6, 'V': 9, 'Q': 5, 'E': 2, 'F': 4, 'C': 8}], ['GAA', {'R': 2, 'I': 8, 'S': 6, 'Y': 5, 'P': 3, 'L': 9, 'K': 7, 'D': 3, 'A': 5, 'T': 8, 'G': 4, 'N': 3, 'M': 8, 'W': 3, 'H': 3, 'V': 4, 'Q': 3, 'E': 6, 'F': 4, 'C': 3}], ['GAC', {'R': 5, 'I': 4, 'S': 2, 'Y': 4, 'P': 7, 'L': 2, 'K': 3, 'D': 7, 'A': 8, 'T': 6, 'G': 9, 'N': 4, 'M': 4, 'W': 6, 'H': 5, 'V': 2, 'Q': 6, 'E': 3, 'F': 4, 'C': 6}], ['GAG', {'R': 6, 'I': 2, 'S': 9, 'Y': 3, 'P': 5, 'L': 9, 'K': 2, 'D': 6, 'A': 2, 'T': 4, 'G': 8, 'N': 6, 'M': 1, 'W': 3, 'H': 4, 'V': 8, 'Q': 5, 'E': 8, 'F': 5, 'C': 1}], ['GAU', {'R': 4, 'I': 4, 'S': 5, 'Y': 9, 'P': 6, 'L': 9, 'K': 4, 'D': 1, 'A': 7, 'T': 8, 'G': 5, 'N': 6, 'M': 7, 'W': 3, 'H': 6, 'V': 2, 'Q': 3, 'E': 2, 'F': 4, 'C': 2}], ['GCA', {'R': 9, 'I': 7, 'S': 2, 'Y': 4, 'P': 7, 'L': 4, 'K': 7, 'D': 7, 'A': 7, 'T': 3, 'G': 4, 'N': 2, 'M': 3, 'W': 4, 'H': 5, 'V': 3, 'Q': 4, 'E': 4, 'F': 6, 'C': 5}], ['GCC', {'R': 5, 'I': 2, 'S': 6, 'Y': 4, 'P': 5, 'L': 5, 'K': 11, 'D': 2, 'A': 5, 'T': 6, 'G': 4, 'N': 4, 'M': 4, 'W': 3, 'H': 8, 'V': 6, 'Q': 4, 'E': 3, 'F': 5, 'C': 5}], ['GCG', {'R': 4, 'I': 6, 'S': 8, 'Y': 7, 'P': 5, 'L': 3, 'K': 7, 'D': 5, 'A': 4, 'T': 7, 'G': 7, 'N': 3, 'M': 2, 'W': 4, 'H': 3, 'V': 5, 'Q': 3, 'E': 6, 'F': 5, 'C': 3}], ['GCU', {'R': 5, 'I': 9, 'S': 4, 'Y': 8, 'P': 2, 'L': 7, 'K': 6, 'D': 0, 'A': 9, 'T': 3, 'G': 6, 'N': 3, 'M': 3, 'W': 6, 'H': 6, 'V': 4, 'Q': 3, 'E': 1, 'F': 3, 'C': 9}], ['GGA', {'R': 3, 'I': 7, 'S': 5, 'Y': 4, 'P': 4, 'L': 10, 'K': 5, 'D': 5, 'A': 7, 'T': 7, 'G': 3, 'N': 3, 'M': 3, 'W': 6, 'H': 4, 'V': 3, 'Q': 7, 'E': 2, 'F': 6, 'C': 3}], ['GGC', {'R': 2, 'I': 5, 'S': 5, 'Y': 3, 'P': 3, 'L': 3, 'K': 5, 'D': 8, 'A': 4, 'T': 11, 'G': 8, 'N': 6, 'M': 6, 'W': 2, 'H': 3, 'V': 5, 'Q': 2, 'E': 5, 'F': 8, 'C': 3}], ['GGG', {'R': 7, 'I': 3, 'S': 10, 'Y': 6, 'P': 6, 'L': 6, 'K': 3, 'D': 10, 'A': 2, 'T': 5, 'G': 2, 'N': 5, 'M': 2, 'W': 3, 'H': 5, 'V': 3, 'Q': 10, 'E': 3, 'F': 1, 'C': 5}], ['GGU', {'R': 6, 'I': 8, 'S': 5, 'Y': 4, 'P': 5, 'L': 8, 'K': 2, 'D': 4, 'A': 2, 'T': 6, 'G': 9, 'N': 8, 'M': 3, 'W': 2, 'H': 5, 'V': 1, 'Q': 5, 'E': 5, 'F': 6, 'C': 3}], ['GUA', {'R': 5, 'I': 4, 'S': 3, 'Y': 4, 'P': 6, 'L': 7, 'K': 2, 'D': 5, 'A': 6, 'T': 5, 'G': 2, 'N': 11, 'M': 3, 'W': 6, 'H': 5, 'V': 4, 'Q': 6, 'E': 5, 'F': 4, 'C': 4}], ['GUC', {'R': 2, 'I': 3, 'S': 5, 'Y': 6, 'P': 6, 'L': 4, 'K': 4, 'D': 4, 'A': 4, 'T': 4, 'G': 1, 'N': 7, 'M': 3, 'W': 4, 'H': 7, 'V': 9, 'Q': 8, 'E': 4, 'F': 8, 'C': 4}], ['GUG', {'R': 5, 'I': 7, 'S': 5, 'Y': 5, 'P': 3, 'L': 3, 'K': 3, 'D': 7, 'A': 4, 'T': 3, 'G': 3, 'N': 5, 'M': 10, 'W': 3, 'H': 3, 'V': 7, 'Q': 3, 'E': 8, 'F': 5, 'C': 5}], ['GUU', {'R': 3, 'I': 0, 'S': 2, 'Y': 4, 'P': 7, 'L': 6, 'K': 7, 'D': 6, 'A': 7, 'T': 3, 'G': 5, 'N': 8, 'M': 7, 'W': 4, 'H': 3, 'V': 5, 'Q': 6, 'E': 6, 'F': 2, 'C': 6}], ['UAA', {'R': 0, 'I': 0, 'S': 0, 'Y': 0, 'P': 0, 'L': 0, 'K': 0, 'D': 0, 'A': 0, 'T': 0, 'G': 0, 'N': 0, 'M': 0, 'W': 0, 'H': 0, 'V': 0, 'Q': 0, 'E': 0, 'F': 0, 'C': 0}], ['UAC', {'R': 4, 'I': 2, 'S': 5, 'Y': 4, 'P': 4, 'L': 2, 'K': 2, 'D': 6, 'A': 4, 'T': 6, 'G': 4, 'N': 9, 'M': 4, 'W': 10, 'H': 5, 'V': 5, 'Q': 3, 'E': 5, 'F': 5, 'C': 8}], ['UAG', {'R': 0, 'I': 0, 'S': 0, 'Y': 0, 'P': 0, 'L': 0, 'K': 0, 'D': 0, 'A': 0, 'T': 0, 'G': 0, 'N': 0, 'M': 0, 'W': 0, 'H': 0, 'V': 0, 'Q': 0, 'E': 0, 'F': 0, 'C': 0}], ['UAU', {'R': 7, 'I': 4, 'S': 3, 'Y': 3, 'P': 7, 'L': 5, 'K': 7, 'D': 6, 'A': 3, 'T': 6, 'G': 4, 'N': 3, 'M': 4, 'W': 4, 'H': 9, 'V': 5, 'Q': 6, 'E': 4, 'F': 1, 'C': 6}], ['UCA', {'R': 6, 'I': 2, 'S': 2, 'Y': 3, 'P': 5, 'L': 7, 'K': 4, 'D': 6, 'A': 2, 'T': 8, 'G': 8, 'N': 5, 'M': 4, 'W': 8, 'H': 3, 'V': 4, 'Q': 4, 'E': 4, 'F': 7, 'C': 5}], ['UCC', {'R': 3, 'I': 2, 'S': 7, 'Y': 5, 'P': 2, 'L': 4, 'K': 4, 'D': 6, 'A': 0, 'T': 10, 'G': 5, 'N': 9, 'M': 4, 'W': 4, 'H': 7, 'V': 5, 'Q': 4, 'E': 4, 'F': 3, 'C': 9}], ['UCG', {'R': 8, 'I': 2, 'S': 6, 'Y': 4, 'P': 8, 'L': 4, 'K': 7, 'D': 4, 'A': 2, 'T': 5, 'G': 3, 'N': 3, 'M': 1, 'W': 9, 'H': 2, 'V': 7, 'Q': 4, 'E': 6, 'F': 5, 'C': 7}], ['UCU', {'R': 4, 'I': 5, 'S': 6, 'Y': 4, 'P': 5, 'L': 3, 'K': 5, 'D': 8, 'A': 5, 'T': 6, 'G': 4, 'N': 8, 'M': 6, 'W': 6, 'H': 4, 'V': 3, 'Q': 6, 'E': 2, 'F': 4, 'C': 3}], ['UGA', {'R': 0, 'I': 0, 'S': 0, 'Y': 0, 'P': 0, 'L': 0, 'K': 0, 'D': 0, 'A': 0, 'T': 0, 'G': 0, 'N': 0, 'M': 0, 'W': 0, 'H': 0, 'V': 0, 'Q': 0, 'E': 0, 'F': 0, 'C': 0}], ['UGC', {'R': 2, 'I': 3, 'S': 6, 'Y': 2, 'P': 4, 'L': 8, 'K': 6, 'D': 3, 'A': 4, 'T': 4, 'G': 5, 'N': 12, 'M': 5, 'W': 6, 'H': 6, 'V': 2, 'Q': 4, 'E': 5, 'F': 5, 'C': 5}], ['UGG', {'R': 3, 'I': 6, 'S': 6, 'Y': 8, 'P': 6, 'L': 6, 'K': 2, 'D': 10, 'A': 2, 'T': 5, 'G': 2, 'N': 1, 'M': 5, 'W': 5, 'H': 3, 'V': 7, 'Q': 7, 'E': 4, 'F': 5, 'C': 4}], ['UGU', {'R': 5, 'I': 5, 'S': 6, 'Y': 5, 'P': 3, 'L': 4, 'K': 5, 'D': 6, 'A': 4, 'T': 10, 'G': 6, 'N': 4, 'M': 8, 'W': 4, 'H': 3, 'V': 7, 'Q': 6, 'E': 2, 'F': 2, 'C': 2}], ['UUA', {'R': 4, 'I': 4, 'S': 4, 'Y': 6, 'P': 2, 'L': 3, 'K': 8, 'D': 2, 'A': 2, 'T': 9, 'G': 3, 'N': 9, 'M': 5, 'W': 7, 'H': 6, 'V': 5, 'Q': 6, 'E': 5, 'F': 4, 'C': 3}], ['UUC', {'R': 1, 'I': 6, 'S': 4, 'Y': 8, 'P': 4, 'L': 5, 'K': 7, 'D': 2, 'A': 8, 'T': 5, 'G': 7, 'N': 7, 'M': 1, 'W': 2, 'H': 4, 'V': 9, 'Q': 2, 'E': 3, 'F': 6, 'C': 6}], ['UUG', {'R': 3, 'I': 3, 'S': 2, 'Y': 5, 'P': 4, 'L': 6, 'K': 6, 'D': 7, 'A': 3, 'T': 4, 'G': 1, 'N': 8, 'M': 6, 'W': 4, 'H': 7, 'V': 7, 'Q': 7, 'E': 5, 'F': 2, 'C': 7}], ['UUU', {'R': 3, 'I': 4, 'S': 4, 'Y': 6, 'P': 6, 'L': 6, 'K': 5, 'D': 3, 'A': 6, 'T': 6, 'G': 4, 'N': 3, 'M': 5, 'W': 8, 'H': 2, 'V': 6, 'Q': 6, 'E': 7, 'F': 5, 'C': 2}]]
```

Comment: Question is not so clear. Could you please provide your dictionary sample? so that you can get some help. else Please share the code you have wrote so far. then people could help more. What I understand is you want to generate chart. but input is not very clear.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this is answering the question but in general [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) is a great tool for this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x[0])
```

This gives you a convenient table.

```
   AAA  AAC  AAG  AAU
A    9    6    6    4
C    5    5    7    7
D    9    5    5    3
E    4    5    5    7
```

Then you can sum over the columns if you like.

```
df.sum(axis=1)
```

resulting in

```
A    290
C    314
D    295
E    292
F    289
G    295
...
```

Or if you would rather create a bar chart for each codon you can do e.g.

```
df.AAA.plot(kind='bar')
```